# Saving JSON from API into Mongo using Mongoose

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a node.js app with Mongo (using the mongoose solution) to create a custom reporting solution with data from the Quickbooks Online API.
Here is the workflow:

1. I authenticate my app with the QBO API
2. I make the API call, and get JSON
3. This is where I would like to parse the JSON to save it to my DB.

The JSON response

```
{ Header: 
{ Time: '2014-09-09T10:55:01-07:00',
 ReportName: 'VendorBalanceDetail',
 StartPeriod: '2014-10-01',
 EndPeriod: '2014-10-09',
 Currency: 'USD',
 Option: [ { Name: 'report_date', Value: '2014-10-09' } ] },
Columns: 
 { Column: 
  [ { ColTitle: 'Date', ColType: 'tx_date' },
    { ColTitle: 'Transaction Type', ColType: 'txn_type' },
    { ColTitle: 'Num', ColType: 'doc_num' },
    { ColTitle: 'Due Date', ColType: 'due_date' },
    { ColTitle: 'Amount', ColType: 'subt_neg_amount' },
    { ColTitle: 'Open Balance', ColType: 'subt_neg_open_bal' },
    { ColTitle: 'Balance', ColType: 'rbal_neg_open_bal' } ] },
Rows: 
 { Row: 
  [ { Header: 
       { ColData: 
          [ { value: 'GS & CO' },
            { value: '' },
            { value: '' },
            { value: '' },
            { value: '' },
            { value: '' },
            { value: '' } ] },
      Rows: 
       { Row: 
          [ { ColData: 
               [ { value: '01/31/2014' },
                 { value: 'Bill' },
                 { value: 'FY/2013-01/2014' },
                 { value: '01/31/2014' },
                 { value: '9963.14' },
                 { value: '9963.14' },
                 { value: '9963.14' } ],
              type: 'Data' },
            { ColData: 
               [ { value: '02/28/2014' },
                 { value: 'Bill' },
                 { value: '02/2014' },
                 { value: '02/28/2014' },
                 { value: '6378.14' },
                 { value: '6378.14' },
                 { value: '16341.28' } ],
              type: 'Data' },
            { ColData: 
               [ { value: '03/31/2014' },
                 { value: 'Bill' },
                 { value: '03/2014' },
                 { value: '03/31/2014' },
                 { value: '2556.0' },
                 { value: '2556.0' },
                 { value: '18897.28' } ],
              type: 'Data' },
            { ColData: 
               [ { value: '04/30/2014' },
                 { value: 'Bill' },
                 { value: '04/2014' },
                 { value: '04/30/2014' },
                 { value: '5221.0' },
                 { value: '5221.0' },
                 { value: '24118.28' } ],
              type: 'Data' },
            { ColData: 
               [ { value: '05/31/2014' },
                 { value: 'Bill' },
                 { value: '05/2014' },
                 { value: '05/31/2014' },
                 { value: '2735.96' },
                 { value: '2735.96' },
                 { value: '26854.24' } ],
              type: 'Data' },
            { ColData: 
               [ { value: '06/30/2014' },
                 { value: 'Bill' },
                 { value: '06/2014' },
                 { value: '06/30/2014' },
                 { value: '658.0' },
                 { value: '658.0' },
                 { value: '27512.24' } ],
              type: 'Data' },
            { ColData: 
               [ { value: '07/31/2014' },
                 { value: 'Bill' },
                 { value: '6-17 to 7-31' },
                 { value: '07/31/2014' },
                 { value: '162.32' },
                 { value: '162.32' },
                 { value: '27674.56' } ],
              type: 'Data' } ] },
      Summary: 
       { ColData: 
          [ { value: 'Total for GS & CO' },
            { value: '' },
            { value: '' },
            { value: '' },
            { value: '27674.56' },
            { value: '27674.56' },
            { value: '' } ] },
      type: 'Section' }
```

My model:

```
 module.exports = mongoose.model('vbDetail', {

company_name: String,
row:{
    date: Date,
    transaction_type: String,
    transaction_num: String,
    due_date: Date,
    amount: Number,
    open_balance: Number,
    balance: Number,
    identifier: String,
    processing_date: Date,
    processing_amount :Date,
    notes: String
}
})
```

The last three fields are custom fields that I want to store in addition to the JSON response.

My question is how to I take the JSON from the response and parse it so it "adheres" to my model?